# Bennies for Long Sessions?

Tags: savage-worlds

In Savage Worlds, Player Bennies refresh at the start of a new session. What is the best way to handle a long session?

For example what if the session is all day or even all weekend?

Comment: I think all three answers are valid, but on balance I like @basilard99 best. I think other GMs might pick one of the other options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer releasing bennies (or in my case 'chips' :)) after a story milestone is reached. So, in a long session, you might have 2-3 big 'events'. I'd refresh the bennies after those.

Answer (score 3):

While [GMNoob has a good answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9092/bennies-for-long-sessions/9094#9094), I think a long session is a great opportunity to use bennies to influence player behavior.  If a player does something cool, or plays to their character, or whatever behavior you're looking for, give them a benny.

In a very long session (a day or more) you would likely want to balance this by giving out bennies on some set schedule, perhaps 8 hours of play.  This keeps less engaged players from being overly neglected.

Comment: Best answer.  Bennies should flow mainly from play not just from the dole.

Answer (score 1):

Set pre-determined time for snack breaks, or declare 2-4 hours blocks of time. At the begining of each of those time blocks, release the bennies!